Connection timed out after update firewall firmware Pgpool-II
I have 2 Application server that have C and Java application that locally connected to pgpool on the same server. Pgpool have connection pool enabled (connection_cache = on). The system has been running without problem.
System
Pgpool 4.4.3 (nurikoboshi)
PostgreSQL 14.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit
We have just updated firewall firmware last week (2024-04-02 from 18:00 to 18:04). Then connection timed out error start to show.
Pgpool health_check failed once but i have set 3 retries for health check so pgpool still alive.
C Applications on the other hand were having connection errors (showing as connection timed out on postgresql logs). And it took 2-3 days for the applications to work properly.
Postgresql master node Logs:
2024-04-02 18:15:53.609 +07 [28375 - ] [user app- app_db _ ss-> 66014a45.6gr7]: LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-04-02 18:16:26.377 +07 [30076 - ] [user app- app_db _ ss-> 65a5edfc.723c]: LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
...
2024-04-02 18:38:17.097 +07 [36106 - ] [user app- app_db _ ss-> 6601c6q8.8h0a]: LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-04-02 18:39:22.633 +07 [21650 - ] [user health_user - health_check _ ss-> 65655788.5322]: LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
...
2024-04-02 20:15:46.185 +07 [40523 - ] [user app - app_db _ ss-> 65388ht1.9a4b]: LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
Application Logs:

20240402-18055307 (00023277)[ORGAP2]     (ORGAP2.pgc ) >> <23277>(ORGAP2) 서버간통신 GW2 POLL 무응답.

20240402-18055307 (00023268)[WB1AP2]     (WB1AP2.pgc ) >> <23268>(WB1AP2) 서버간통신 WEB2 POLL 무응답.

20240402-18055307 (00017997)[BK1AP]      (BK1AP.pgc  ) >> <17997>(BK1AP) 서버간통신 GW1 POLL 무응답.

20240402-18055307 (00017996)[ORGAP]      (ORGAP.pgc  ) >> <17996>(ORGAP) 서버간통신 GW1 POLL 무응답.

20240402-18055308 (00023264)[BK1AP2]     (BK1AP2.pgc ) >> <23264>(BK1AP2) 서버간통신 GW2 POLL 무응답.

20240402-18060561 (00023223)[WB1AP]      (WB1AP.pgc  ) >> <23223>(WB1AP) 서버간통신 WEB1 POLL 무응답.


...

20240402-18342396 (00026121)[BK1AP]      (BK1AP.pgc  ) >> <26121>(BK1AP) 서버간통신 GW1 소켓접속 오류발생.

20240402-18342396 (00026122)[ORGAP]      (ORGAP.pgc  ) >> <26122>(ORGAP) 서버간통신 GW1 소켓접속 오류발생.

20240402-18342396 (00026124)[BK1AP2]     (BK1AP2.pgc ) >> <26124>(BK1AP2) 서버간통신 GW2 소켓접속 오류발생.

20240402-18342396 (00026120)[ORGAP2]     (ORGAP2.pgc ) >> <26120>(ORGAP2) 서버간통신 GW2 소켓접속 오류발생.


I want to make this process faster so that update firewall firmware will not affect current state of the system. I will appreciate any help here. Thanks

Perhaps you should blame the firewall...

Yes it's the firewall but i'm wondering if there is a solution to this. So that I don't need to care for firewall firmware update anymore :D

There may be, but hardware/network/installation problems are off-topic here. You should open a service request with the firewall vendor.

Thank you. I will contact them. But I think there is a way to kill the old cached connection of pgpool automatically when firewall updated so that

Connection timed out problem solved when connection killed.
My application with auto reconnect mechanism will create a new connection.

